# Is there a method for calculating a regression coefficient for an a priori equation (e.g. R^2 for y=x)?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I have a data set where I want to see how well the line y=x describes the variance of y as opposed to a standard regression that tries to examine the best fit, as from a theoretical stand point the best case scenario is that y does equal x, and I want to demonstrate how close the data is to accomplishing that. Essentially I want to be able to calculate the R^2 value when I specify the the predicted y values. I have attempted to do so by calculating SSR and SST for the data in a spreadsheet, but my R^2 value increases to .59 compared to the .30 that SPSS calculates (double checked my spreadsheet/math by using the regression equation that SPSS calculates (y0.976x - 6.5) and that is all good), where as my expectation is that the regression coefficient should decrease, as the standard regression line *should* be a better fit.

---

So my questions are two fold:
1) Is there an accepted term for this, where I have an *a priori* equation I want to evaluate as a regression model? And
2) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is hard to say without further details as to how exactly you proceeded.

Comment: What additional details would be helpful?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194906/test-dispersion-around-y-x-line and its references to concordance correlation.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly point out, the regression line should maximize $R^2$, so there must be a mistake somewhere, but given your description this is hard to find.

One issue is that the definition of the standard centered $R^2$ requires the regression to have a constant, which $y=x$ does not, as it constrains the regression through the origin. I have however not been capable of replicating your outcome of a larger $R^2$ given this possible explanation. See the following little simulation R:

```
reps <- 10000
difference <- rep(NA,reps)

for (i in 1:reps){
  x <- runif(20)
  y <- x + rnorm(20, sd=.01) # i.e. data is generated according to "best-case scenario"
  difference[i] <- summary(lm(y~x))$r.squared - (1-mean((y-x)^2)/mean((y-mean(y))^2)) # difference in standard R^2 and a manual one when y=x yields SSR
}
> min(difference) # is > 0
[1] 1.34675e-08
```